# How to use Matplotlib to make a visual graph for a program running around 100 trials of 10,000 iterations each?

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is my current Python code:

```py
import random
import math
import time
import statistics

def approximate_phi(num_points):
    inside_circle = 0

    for _ in range(num_points):
        x = random.uniform(0, 1)
        y = random.uniform(0, 1)

        # Check if the point (x, y) is inside the quarter circle
        if x**2 + y**2 <= 1:
            inside_circle += 1

    # Approximate phi using the formula: phi^2 ≈ 5/6 * (pi)
    phi_squared_approximation = (5/6) * (4 * inside_circle / num_points)

    # Take the square root to approximate phi
    phi_approximation = math.sqrt(phi_squared_approximation)
    return phi_approximation

# Number of trials
num_trials = 100

# Number of random points to generate in each trial
num_points_per_trial = 10000

phi_values = []

# Measure the time taken for each of the 100 trials
trial_times = []
for _ in range(num_trials):
    start_time = time.time()
    phi = approximate_phi(num_points_per_trial)
    end_time = time.time()
    phi_values.append(phi)
    trial_times.append(end_time - start_time)

# Calculate actual value of phi
actual_phi = (1 + math.sqrt(5)) / 2

# Calculate mean and median values
mean_phi = statistics.mean(phi_values)
median_phi = statistics.median(phi_values)

# Calculate percentage difference from actual phi
percentage_difference_mean = ((mean_phi - actual_phi) / actual_phi) * 100
percentage_difference_median = ((median_phi - actual_phi) / actual_phi) * 100

# Calculate standard deviation
phi_std_deviation = statistics.stdev(phi_values)

# Calculate average time per iteration and per trial in milliseconds
average_time_per_iteration = statistics.mean(trial_times)
average_time_per_trial = average_time_per_iteration * num_points_per_trial

print("")
print("Results of the Improved Monte Carlo Simulation:")
print("")
print(f"Actual value of phi                             : {actual_phi}")
print(f"Mean value of phi from {num_trials} trials               : {mean_phi}")
print(f"Median value of phi from {num_trials} trials             : {median_phi}")
print(f"Percentage difference (mean) from actual phi    : {percentage_difference_mean:.10f}%")
print(f"Percentage difference (median) from actual phi  : {percentage_difference_median:.10f}%")
print(f"Average time per iteration                      : {average_time_per_iteration:.8f} ms")
print(f"Average time per trial                          : {average_time_per_trial:.8f} ms")
print(f"Standard deviation of phi values                : {phi_std_deviation:.8f}")
```

I need help in modifying the code in order to make a visual graph for each of 100 trials, with the value of 'phi' on the y-axis, and the number of iterations on the x-axis.

I haven't been able to try much, and am really confused by this, since I've never used Matplotlib before. I do know what the graph is supposed to look like, from other sources.
This is what the result should ideally look like:
[image: graph]

Comment: The lines in your plot look to have serial correlation, which would imply saving intermediate results from your `approximate_phi` function.  Is either deliberate?

Comment: @SamMason The plot is not mine, i found the plot online as a reference material for how the code should look. But to answer your question, yes, the program would need to save intermediate results in order to display the graph I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep hold of the estimate for all iterations up to your 10,000.  An efficient way to do that is to use numpy to work on arrays rather than scalars.

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Set up a random number generator
rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=42)

def approximate_phi(num_points):
    
    x = rng.uniform(0, 1, size=num_points)
    y = rng.uniform(0, 1, size=num_points)

    # Check if each point (x, y) is inside the quarter circle
    inside_circle = x**2 + y**2 <= 1

    # Use a cumulative sum to get the total for all sample sizes up to num_points
    inside_circle_total = np.cumsum(inside_circle)

    # Approximate phi using the formula: phi^2 ≈ 5/6 * (pi)
    phi_squared_approximation = (5/6) * (4 * inside_circle_total / np.arange(1, num_points + 1))

    # Take the square root to approximate phi
    phi_approximation = np.sqrt(phi_squared_approximation)
    
    return phi_approximation

# Number of trials
num_trials = 100

# Number of random points to generate in each trial
num_points_per_trial = 10000

phi_values = []
for _ in range(num_trials):
    phi = approximate_phi(num_points_per_trial)
    phi_values.append(phi)

# Calculate actual value of phi
actual_phi = (1 + math.sqrt(5)) / 2

# Set up Matplotlib figure and axes
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5), layout='constrained')

# Plot the individual trials
x = np.arange(1, num_points_per_trial + 1)
phi_values = np.transpose(phi_values)  # So plot interprets each trial as one line

ax.plot(x, phi_values, color='black', linewidth=0.5)

# Plot actual value
ax.axhline(actual_phi, linestyle='dashed', color='red', linewidth=2, label='Phi')

# Plot average and 90th percentile
ax.plot(x, np.mean(phi_values, axis=1), color='blue', linewidth=2, label='Average')
ax.plot(x, np.percentile(phi_values, 90, axis=1), color='green', linewidth=2, label='90th percentile')

# Set some reasonable axes limits (by default y may go down to zero).
ax.set_xlim(1, num_points_per_trial + 1)
ax.set_ylim(bottom=1.25)

# Axis labels
ax.set_xlabel('Iterations')
ax.set_ylabel('Phi Approximation')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: a nice bit of work. I believe this is the best (most optimal) approach.